# Excel get range for named dynamic range (OFFSET)

Tags: excel, vba

hi I have a data Validation for a dropdown cell on Sheet1, the List is a named dynamic range whose equation is: 
 =OFFSET(Sheet2!$J$3,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!$J:$J)-2,1)

Works fine.

But now I want to get the Excel cell reference for this; in my example the range is sheet2!$j$3:$j$30. I need that string to put into a Range reference

I've done this by parsing but slows down my spreadsheet

Comment: Is this a `excel-vba` question, or a `excel-formulas` question?  Would the formula `=ADDRESS(ROW($J$3),COLUMN($J$3),1,1,"Sheet2")&":"&ADDRESS(ROW($J$3)+COUNTA(Sheet2!$J:$J)-2,COLUMN($J$3)+1,1,1)` work?   (I'm sure there must be a better way than that though.)

Comment: Just noticed (after posting a VBA solution) that I was getting one more row and column than the OFFSET function would have, therefore the formula would really be `=ADDRESS(ROW($J$3),COLUMN($J$3),1,1,"Sheet2")&":"&ADDRESS(RO‌​W($J$3)+COUNTA(Sheet‌​2!$J:$J)-3,COLUMN($J‌​$3),1,1)`

Answer (score 1):

A VBA solution to the question you asked might be:

```
Dim x as String
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    x = "'" & .Name & "'!" & .Range("J3", .Range("J3").Offset(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns("J")) - 2, 0)).Address
End With
'The value of variable x is now the address you asked for
```

but maybe what you are really trying to do is:

```
Dim rng As Range
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rng = .Range("J3:J" & .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
'rng will now be a Range object referring to everything in
' column J, starting at row 3 and ending at the last
' non-blank cell in column J
```

Comment: perfect, thanks Yow! I am using the 1st solution as I have at OFFSET from a dynamic named range.
(I voted up but I am new to StackOverflow, so it will not show in the publicly displaced post... )

Comment: @LukeB - See Thomas Inzina's answer - it is probably much, much better than my 1st solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything special.  The formula will return a valid range.

[image]

Comment: Well, would you look at that!!  I didn't realise that you could do such a calculation in that spot - I definitely learn something new every day.  (Now if I could just work out how to trick SO into letting me do a +2 I would be really happy!)

Comment: LOL...I think that SO should have a special platinum badge `"Gray-Hatter"` that you can only get by hacking the site!

Comment: The closest I would be able to get to a `"Gray-Hatter"` badge would be if they issued me with a `"Grey-Hair"` badge.