# Spreadsheet formulas causing workbook to be slow

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting "Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas. As a result, these formulas cannot be evaluated." So I disabled multi threading. My spreadsheet still has the issue of being slow. I run many formulas most being combination of vlookup or multi criteria index matches.

example formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Total'!B2:K36, 
 MATCH(1,INDEX(('Control Manager'!$C$2= 'Total'!A:A) * (A32 = 'Total'!1:1),),0)),"-")
```

How can I speed up my spreadsheet?

Comment: The fact that you are analyzing the entirety of column A is causing trouble. Do you need to look at all ~1M rows. If not, set the lower bound (e.g. A1:A10000 instead of A:A)

Comment: yes i could probably limit it to 1000, would this help alot?

Comment: By a factor of approximately 1000, yes.

Comment: Did the provide answer solve your problem. If so, please kindly click the green check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Total'!B2:K36, 
MATCH(1,INDEX(('Control Manager'!$C$2= 'Total'!$A$2:$A$1000) * (A32 = 'Total'!1:1),),0)),"-")
```

Comment: You should also look into setting up a dynamic range with the range naming system. This will allow the range within column A to adjust as you add/remove items.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360167/excel-get-range-for-named-dynamic-range-offset